# Sorting normal arrays in ascending or descending order

Tags: objective-c

How can I sort the objects in a normal array (non-NSArray) by ascending or descending order (given that all of the objects in the array are integers)? Is this even possible?

Here is my code:

```
int areas[detectedBlobs.size()];

for (int i = 0; i < detectedBlobs.size(); i++)
{
    areas[i] = detectedBlobs[i].getWidth() * detectedBlobs[i].getHeight(); 
}

NSSortDescriptor *sortOrder = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey: @"self"
                                                            ascending: NO];
return [areas sortedArrayUsingDescriptors: [NSArray arrayWithObject: sortOrder]]; // error is here
```

Comment: What's stopping you from running a simple search on your own?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If by "normal array" you mean a C array then use the standard library function `qsort()`. Type `man 3 qsort` in the Terminal if your Xcode doesn't have man pages as part of its docs.

If by "all of the objects in the array are integers" you mean they are `NSNumber` instances then provided you define the sorting function you pass to `qsort()` in a `.m` file then it can make Objective-C method calls to obtain the integer values from the `NSNumber` objects.

Answer (score 0):

```
NSSortDescriptor* sortOrder = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey: @"self" 
                                                        ascending: NO];
return [myArray sortedArrayUsingDescriptors: [NSArray arrayWithObject: sortOrder]];
```

**USE SORT DISCRIPTOR**

**after edit**

**you have to convert it to number first**

```
NSNumberFormatter * f = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[f setNumberStyle:NSNumberFormatterDecimalStyle];
NSNumber * myNumber = [f numberFromString:string];
```

Comment: I tried this, but I'm getting a "Bad receiver type int *" error on the return line.

Comment: Yes i will give you the full answer

Comment: Please tell me the full answer.

Comment: What should I put in place of myNumber and string?

Comment: Please Share your. Code with me